# Calculate the number

Tags: java

Basically there is this very large grid of letters that only consist of letter a, b, and c:

Given that grid of letters, find the number of "abc" that aligned vertically. Constraint number of columns is [1...1,000,000,000], number of rows is [1...1,000]

I haven't come up with any solutions in my head. Anyone got a clue regarding this problem? What approach should I use to solve this kind of problem? Is it Dynamic Programming?

Comment: Usually I put one character after another in the correct order. Hasn't failed me so far. Works in C++ and Java.

Comment: have you managed to count the occurrences for small values of rows and columns

Comment: that would thus be the continuation. whenever you find a group abc in some column, it may holds true for the next columns. How long does it hold true is the goal of your optimization

Comment: Is it always "abc" you need to find? Or is that just an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the input is relatively small compared to the grid it represents (because the sizes of the groups are relatively great), it is more efficient to *not* create the grid. You can achieve *O(G.log(R))* time complexity, where *G* is the total number of groups, and *R* the number of rows.

Perform these steps:

1. Transform the groups so they have the ending x-offset instead of size. So for your first example you would get these rows of groups (I will assume an array variable `rows`):

   ```
   [
     [['a', 8], ['b', 16], ['c', 23]],
     [['a', 3], ['b', 19], ['c', 23]],
     [['c', 6], ['b', 10], ['a', 15], ['b', 20]]
   ]
   ```
2. Per row, maintain a current x-offset (all initialised at 0), and current character (initialised to the first character of each row, so ['a', 'a', 'c'] in the example. Let's call these two arrays `offset` and `current`. They have as many entries as there are rows.
3. Put the row indexes in a priority queue (min-heap), keyed by their first x-offset, and pop the first group from each row (as they have been processed). So in the example, the heap would initially have the keys 8, 3 and 6 (with 3 at the root). Combined with the corresponding row indexes, the heap would have these key/value pairs:

   ```
   [[3, 1],[8, 0],[6, 2]]
   ```
4. As long as the heap is not empty perform the following steps
5. Extract the minimum x-offset (`x`) from the heap with its corresponding row index (`i`).
6. Extract the first element of `rows[i]` (so remove it), and if the x-offset in that element is not greater than the grid's with, push a new key/value pair on the heap: [that x-offset, the same row index]. If the row was empty, then use a value for the x-offset that is larger than any x-offset (Infinity, or maxWidth + 1). NB: Make sure the removal of the first element of a row happens in constant time. For instance, use a deque data structure for it.
7. Check whether the character at the retrieved row index `i` is part of "abc". You can use `current` (see step 2) for this check. Only check at `current[i-2], ..., current[i+2]`. Some checks are needed to avoid you get out of range here (i.e. when `i < 2`). When there is a match with the "a" at `current[j]` (there can only be one), get the greatest x-offset from `offset[j], offset[j+1], offset[j+2]`, as that corresponds to the start of the "abc" pattern. The pattern ends at `x`, the index we popped from the heap in step 5. So add this difference in offsets to the overall count (of "abc" occurrences).
8. Update `curr[i]` to the character that was popped from the row in step 6 (or, if in step 6 the row was empty, use a space instead), and update `offset[i]` to the `x` popped from the heap in step 5.
9. Repeat from step 4.

When this loop is done, we will have the total count of occurrences.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which executes on the two examples you have given:

```js
// Heap implementation, since JavaScript has no native one (yet)
const MinHeap = {siftDown(arr, i=0, value=arr[i]) {if (i >= arr.length) return;let key = value[0];while (true) {let j = i*2+1;if (j+1 < arr.length && arr[j][0] > arr[j+1][0]) j++;if (j >= arr.length || key <= arr[j][0]) break;arr[i] = arr[j];i = j;}arr[i] = value;},heapify(arr) {for (let i = arr.length>>1; i--; ) this.siftDown(arr, i);return arr;},pop(arr) {return this.exchange(arr, arr.pop());},exchange(arr, value) {if (!arr.length) return value;let oldValue = arr[0];this.siftDown(arr, 0, value);return oldValue;},push(arr, value) {let key = value[0];let i = arr.length;let j;while ((j = (i-1)>>1) >= 0 && key < arr[j][0]) {arr[i] = arr[j];i = j;}arr[i] = value;return arr;}};

function countAbc(charGroups) {  
    let curr = [];
    let offset = Array(charGroups).fill(0);
    let list = [];
    let width = 0;
    for (let y = 0; y < charGroups.length; y++) {
        let row = charGroups[y];
        let [ch, x] = row.shift(); // This shift must be O(1), which is not guaranteed in JS
        curr.push(ch);
        list.push([x, y]);
        for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            let group = row[i];
            x += group[1];
            group[1] = x;
        }
        width = Math.max(width, x);
    }
    
    let heap = MinHeap.heapify(list);
    let count = 0;
    while (heap.length) {
        let [xEnd, y] = MinHeap.pop(heap);
        let row = charGroups[y];
        // Again: shift must be O(1), which is not guaranteed in JS
        let [ch, x] = row.length ? row.shift() : [' ', width+1];
        if (x <= width) MinHeap.push(heap, [x, y]);
        let y0 = Math.max(0, y-2);
        let i = curr.slice(y0, y+3).join("").indexOf("abc");
        if (i >= 0) {
            let prevX = Math.max(...offset.slice(y0+i, y0+i+3));
            count += xEnd - prevX;
        }
        curr[y] = ch;
        offset[y] = xEnd;
    }
    return count;
}

// Example runs:
let input, result;

console.log(countAbc([
    [['a', 8], ['b', 8], ['c', 7]],
    [['a', 3], ['b', 16], ['c', 4]],
    [['c', 6], ['b', 4], ['a', 5], ['b', 5]]
]));
console.log(countAbc([
    [['a', 900000], ['b', 100000]],
    [['a', 750000], ['b', 250000]],
    [['a', 250000], ['c', 750000]], 
]));
```